# Mysql Group_concat where in again group concat how can i manage

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

### when i run this query result is getting

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId`) 
FROM `recipe_ingredient` 
WHERE `recipe_ingredient`.`ingredientId` 
    IN(4,11,33,36,54,117,135,136,178,185,218,312,348,378)
ORDER BY `recipeId` ASC
```

---

but i want above query "IN" value i getting from other table so i am creating new query but i am not getting result

### see below new query here

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId`) 
FROM `recipe_ingredient` 
WHERE `recipe_ingredient`.`ingredientId` 
    IN(
        SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(`ingredient`.`ingredientId` 
        ORDER BY `ingredient`.`ingredientId` ASC ) AS unlinkIng 
        FROM `ingredient` 
        WHERE `ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN(4,178) or    `ingredient`.`linkIngredientPerent` IN(4,178)
)
ORDER BY `recipeId` ASC
```

Comment: can you show what result of SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`ingredient`.`ingredientId` ORDER BY `ingredient`.`ingredientId` ASC ) AS unlinkIng FROM `ingredient` WHERE `ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN(4,178) or `ingredient`.`linkIngredientPerent` IN(4,178)

Comment: Yes already i am get this ID - 4,11,33,36,54,117,135,136,178,185,218,312,348,378  #Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `GROUP_CONCAT` from the subquery:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(`recipe_ingredient`.`recipeId`) 
FROM 
    `recipe_ingredient` 
WHERE 
    `recipe_ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN (SELECT `ingredient`.`ingredientId` AS unlinkIng 
                                           FROM `ingredient` 
                                           WHERE `ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN (4, 178) 
                                              OR `ingredient`.`linkIngredientPerent` IN (4, 178))
ORDER BY 
    `recipeId` ASC
```

---

Answer (score 0):

What is the result you are getting in subquery? Please confirm that first whether its returning any result. Otherwise Query seems fine.

```
SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(`ingredient`.`ingredientId` 
        ORDER BY `ingredient`.`ingredientId` ASC ) AS unlinkIng 
        FROM `ingredient` 
        WHERE `ingredient`.`ingredientId` IN(4,178) or    `ingredient`.`linkIngredientPerent` IN(4,178)
```

Comment: YES i am getting result that 4,11,33,36,54,117,135,136,178,185,218,312,348,378

Comment: Query seems fine dude. Is it that you getting any error when executing whole query? Or it simply doesn't returns any records? Hope you passing correct columns names.